# How to modify a storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM using RightScale

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, rightscale

I'm tring to modify the default storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM on a 5.5 DB Parameter Group (for a RDS instance hosted in Amazon). But I am unable to change, since the property shows up as non modifiable. How do I achieve this via RightScale or Amazon RDS

default_storage_engine  string
dynamic     system  InnoDB  The default storage engine (table type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 3 ways to set this. 2 set it for all sessions on server start-up and the third sets it for the current session.

1. When starting MySQL use the `--default-storage-engine=MYISAM` startup option
2. In the my.cnf file set the `default-storage-engine=MYISAM` option
3. In your current session `SET storage_engine=MYISAM;`

I suspect one of the first two are the best so you don't accidentally end up without it set one session. On Amazon RDS you need to set this via a [DB Parameter Group](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2935).

On RightScale you need to tune the [Chef Cookbook](http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/Multi_Cloud/Chef/Using_Chef_Cookbooks_with_RightScale/Auto-Tune_MySQL_for_Database_Manager_for_MySQL_%28Chef%29). You should just need to set the default-storage-engine in my.cnf.erb.